# Calculate difference between two times in Java

Tags: java, time, operation

I have a doubt. I need to create a program in Java where for example I input 2 times = `14 25 12` and `7 50 25`, and it subtracts to `6:34:47`. How can I do that without using any API class from Java? I can only use Scanner and `if` statements. I tried something like below but obviously it doesnt work because for exemple for the seconds it does `12-25 = -13` and it should be 47.

```
int seconds = seconds2 - seconds1;
int minutes = minutes2 - minutes1;
int hours = hours2 - hours1;
```

This doesn’t work.

Comment: This is maths basics, not Java code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with math calculation and substraction and not code problem

Comment: *"How can i do that without using any API class from JAVA"* - You don't. Date/time manipulation IS NOT SIMPLE maths, it as any number of complicated rules associated with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard of *carryover*?

If diff value is <0, add 60 and subtract 1 from next higher value.

From **7 50 25** to **14 25 12**:
`hour = 14 - 7 = 7`
`minute = 25 - 50 = -25`
`second = 12 - 25 = -13`

So add 60 seconds, and subtract 1 minute:
`second = -13 + 60 = 47`
`minute = -25 - 1 = -26`

So add 60 minutes, and subtract 1 hour:
`minute = -26 + 60 = 34`
`hour = 7 - 1 = 6`

Result:
`hour = 6`
`minute = 34`
`second = 47`

**6 34 47**

Comment: Thanks this was definitly a math problem, sorry to bother and thanks for the answer